# Is it possible to use OS variables to define JSON object for Cypress configuration?

Tags: cypress

It is possible to define an OS variable then refer to it in the Cypress code:

```
export CYPRESS_HOST=laura.dev.local
```

then in code:

```
Cypress.env('HOST')
```

however I would like to define more complex structure:

```
"obj": {
   "keyA": "valA",
   "keyB": "valB"
}
```

Is it possible to achieve that with Cypress and OS variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an OS env variable as a string:

```
$ export CYPRESS_HOST="{\"obj\":{\"keyA\":\"valA\",\"keyB\":\"valB\"}}"
```

then it will be loaded as an object in Cypress, so you can work with it like with an object:

```js
cy
  .log(Cypress.env('HOST'));
```

[image]

You can get some value:

```js
cy
  .log(Cypress.env('HOST').obj.keyA);
```

[image]